# CakePHP: Where To Place This Function

Tags: cakephp

I have 3 models: Student, Course and StudentCourse. Course 'hasAndBelongsToMany' Student, Student 'hasMany' Course, and StudentCourse 'belongsTo' Student and Course. Before a student can signup for a course, I need to check a few things (ie: is the course full, has that student taken that course in the past, etc). I can handle the logic inside of the function, but which model should I place that function under? And, how should it be called? One way I thought of was:

```
// Student Model
public function canSignupForCourse($studentId, $courseId) {
    // is the course full?
    // have they signed up before, etc
    // return either true or false
}

// Could it then be called anywhere as:
if($this->Student->canSignupForCourse($studentId, $courseId)) {
    // etc
}
```

Or, is there a better/easier way to do it (and, do I need to send both the studentid and courseid each time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best thing to do is to try to implement these restrictions as validation rule in the model.

According to your description, applying a student for a course is done by creating a new `StudentCourse`, so that's where you should try to fit the validation rules, for example:

```
// StudentCourse.php

$validate = array(
    'course_id' => array(
         'rule' => array('maxStudents', 30),
         'required' => true,
         'on' => 'create'
    )
)

function maxStudents($check, $max) {
    $count = $this->find('count', array(
        'conditions' => array('course_id' => $check['course_id']),
        'contain' => false
    ));
    return $count < $max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd first check out the example in the manual here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model

This should convince you that you should probably make Student 'hasAndBelongsToMany' course as well (since Course `has` student but student doesnt `belongto` course in your model relationships)

You can then define that relationship model as something like CourseMembership (as in the example link above)

I would then put canSignupForCourse function in that model.  However I'd probably split this function up into a few separate ones, like courseNotFull and courseNotTakenBefore

I would then put these functions into the model's validate object like so:

```
public $validate = array( 
    'course_id' => array(
        'courseNotFull' => array( 
            'rule' => array('courseNotFull'), 
            'message' => "Course is full", 
        ), 
        'courseNotTakenBefore' => array(
           'rule' => array('courseNotTakenBefore'), 
            'message' => "Student has taken course before", 
        )
    )
);
```

And define the model functions like this:

```
function courseNotFull() {
    $this->Course->id = $this->data[$this->alias]['course_id'];
    $course = $this->Course->read();

    return $course['Course']['isFull'];
}

function courseTakenBefore() {
    $this->Student->id = $this->data[$this->alias]['student_id'];
    $this->Course->id = $this->data[$this->alias]['course_id'];

    $course = $this->Student->Course->findById($this->Course->id);

    return $course;
}
```

Now whenever you try to save or validate() CourseMembership, the validate will return a descriptive error message if it is unsuccessful.

Comment: using this, how would I go about creating a new CourseMembership (how can I set the course_id and student_id)?

Comment: Same as any other model.  Lets say a student was logged in and trying to register for a course.  His student ID could be accessed by something like http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user .  The course_id should be submitted with the post data.  Then in your controller you can add in student_id to $this->request->data, and call 
$this->CourseMembership->create();
$this->CourseMembership->save($this->request->data);

The cool thing about this is you can add extra info to a particular membership, such as attendance & grades